# Spring batch with cassandra native driver

Tags: cassandra, spring-batch, datastax-java-driver, spring-batch-admin

Can anyone show an example of using latest Spring batch framework with Cassandra? How to set the driver class if I use the thrift driver from Datastax?

Comment: The driver from DataStax does not use thrift, it uses CQL. Thrift is deprecated

Comment: Is native driver equal to cql driver or is it something different?

Comment: CQL and native driver are the same for C*

Answer (score 1):

Try Using this..,

```html
<bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:cassandra://localhost:8988/keyspace" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You could add some explanation to improve your answer.